# Microsoft Word 2010 Macro Issue

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, macros, shapes

Here's a macro I recorded, but it won't run. When I click on the name and the on Run, nothing appears. I know how to record and use them, but I can't get recorded macros to run for the ff: Circle Red (below), or any text box I try to record.

```
       .Shadow = wdUndefined
        .Outline = wdUndefined
        .Emboss = wdUndefined
        .Engrave = wdUndefined
        .AllCaps = wdUndefined
        .Hidden = wdUndefined
        .Underline = wdUndefined
        .Color = wdColorRed
        .Size = wdUndefined
        .Animation = wdUndefined
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Name = ""
    End With
    .LinkedStyle = ""
End With
ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
    ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
    False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
    wdWord10ListBehavior
End Sub

Sub CircleRed()
'
' CircleRed Macro
'
'
End Sub
```

Comment: I've edited your post so the macro is readable, but it still doesn't make sense. Is this all in the right order? Because if it is, then you are missing a lot of code. Its like you deleted some of the beginning of the code, which is why it is not working. For example, there should be 2 `with` statements defined, and a `Sub name` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this code is all you have, it is clear you are missing some important parts.

My suggestion is to remove all code and rerecord the macro. It'll be much quicker to do it this way than to learn how to program VBA and fix it.